# ¿como puedo mostrar el nombre de la carrera en lugar del id?

Tags: mysql, sql

lo que quiero saber es la sintaxis de una funcion en php que me ayude a que en el atributo en lugar del numero de id me muestre el nombre de la carrera, ya que el campo carrera es una foreign key.

```
<div id="mostrar">
        <table class="tabla">
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
                <th>Carrera</th>
            </tr>
            
            <?php 
                require_once "conexion/conexion.php";

                $cons="SELECT * FROM personal";
                $res=mysqli_query($conn, $cons);

                foreach($res as $r) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $r['Nombre']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Apellido_p']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Apellido_m']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Edad']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Id_carrera']?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero deberías modificar tu consulta, y hacer un join con la tabla donde tengas el nombre de tu carrera, te muestro un ejemplo asumiendo que tu tabla de carreras se llama **carreras** y el id de esta se guarda en la columna **Id_carrera**, ademas debes tener la columna donde se guarda el nombre de tu carrera, en el ejemplo yo uso **nombre**.
Después, en lugar de mostrar `$r['Id_carrera']`, mostrá el alias con el que llamaste al nombre de la carrera en la base de datos, en el caso del ejemplo use `$r['nombre_carrera']`:

```
<div id="mostrar">
        <table class="tabla">
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
                <th>Carrera</th>
            </tr>
            
            <?php 
                require_once "conexion/conexion.php";

                $cons="SELECT p.*, c.nombre as nombre_carrera FROM personal p inner join carreras c on p.Id_carrera = c.Id_carrera";
                $res=mysqli_query($conn, $cons);

                foreach($res as $r) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $r['Nombre']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Apellido_p']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Apellido_m']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Edad']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['nombre_carrera']?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nicolas Acosta. Muchas gracias si me fue de gran ayuda el ejemplo

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero que hagas un INNER JOIN con la tabla que tenga el nombre de la carrera.

```
<div id="mostrar">
        <table class="tabla">
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                <th>Edad</th>
                <th>Carrera</th>
            </tr>
            
            <?php 
                require_once "conexion/conexion.php";

                $cons="SELECT pe.Nombre,pe.Apellido_p,pe.Apellido_m,pe.Edad,te.Especialidad
                       FROM tabla_especialidad te INNER JOIN personal pe
                       ON te.idPersonal = pe.idPersonal";

                $res=mysqli_query($conn, $cons);

                foreach($res as $r) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $r['Nombre']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Apellido_p']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Apellido_m']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Edad']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $r['Especialidad']?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Tu tabla especialidad debe estar relacionada con personal.

```
$cons="SELECT pe.Nombre,pe.Apellido_p,pe.Apellido_m,pe.Edad,te.Especialidad
                       FROM tabla_especialidad te INNER JOIN personal pe
                       ON te.idPersonal = pe.idPersonal";
```

Comment: idPersonal hace referencia a tu primary key de la tabla de persona, la cual debe estar referenciada en la tabla especialidad como Foreign key.

Comment: Daniel Rodriguez muchas gracias  por tu colaboracion, si me ayudo!!

Answer (score 0):

Hacer esto:

```
SELECT * FROM personal
```

Involucra que solo vas a obtener los registros de la entidad `personal`, lo cual involucra solo obtener el valor numérico almacenado en la columna `id_carrera`y hasta ahi esta bien lo que te devuelve.

Sin embargo consideremos que el valor numérico previamente mencionado es una referencia a un valor contenido en otra tabla en este caso `carreras` dado lo cual la consulta debe involucrar a ambas tablas.

Para lo anterior te apoyarás de `JOINS` y para ser mas específico de `INNER JOIN/JOIN` que te regresará los valores de la tabla carreras que tengan al menos un registro relacionado con la tabla `personal` (*descartando a aquellos registros de personal que no tengan ninguna carrera asociada*)

Entonces la estructura debe quedar mas o menos así:

```
SELECT tabla1.columna,
       tabla2.columna
FROM tablaUno
INNER JOIN tablaDos ON tablaUno.llavePrimaria = tablaDos.llaveForanea;
```

Donde:

- Tabla1 será la tabla `carreras` (por que es la que tiene a la llave primaria)
- Tabla2 será la tabla `personal` (por que es la que contiene a la llave foránea que te vincula con `carreras`)

**Referencia**

- [JOINS en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)

Comment: Beta M. muchas gracias por tu ayuda